# dynamic auto-resize control on animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am trying to animate element by moving it from one cell to another using following animation code.

```
    private void PerformAnimation(List<Tuple<int, int>> _path, UIElement sprite)
    {
        Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames row_intKeyFrame = new Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        row_intKeyFrame.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, _path.Count * 500);

        Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames col_intKeyFrame = new Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        col_intKeyFrame.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, _path.Count * 500);

        for (int i = 1; i < _path.Count; i++)
        {
            row_intKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteInt32KeyFrame(_path[i].Item2));
            col_intKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteInt32KeyFrame(_path[i].Item1));
        }


        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(row_intKeyFrame, new PropertyPath("(Grid.Row)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(col_intKeyFrame, new PropertyPath("(Grid.Column)"));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(row_intKeyFrame, sprite);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(col_intKeyFrame, sprite);

        storyBoard.Children.Add(row_intKeyFrame);
        storyBoard.Children.Add(col_intKeyFrame);
        storyBoard.Begin();

    }
```

Now in a cell if there already exist an UIElement i need to resize both of them and re-add it to that cell.

[image]

```
   private void ResizeControls(int destRow, int destCol)
    {
            Grid Parent;
            List<UIElement> listOfElements = (BoardGrid.Children
                      .Cast<UIElement>()
                      .Where(i => Grid.GetRow(i) == destRow && Grid.GetColumn(i) == destCol)).ToList();

            if (listOfElements.Count > 1)
            {
               // Resize controls here
            }
   }
```

Now when an element moves from one cell to another it can be either in 2 states i.e. resized or normal. Whenever it moves to an cell which already has an UI element i need them to get in resized mode so that they can fit and when they move to a free cell i.e (a cell that doesnt has any UI control i need to move them back to normal state again). How can i achieve this functionality ? Do i need to add any panel in that cell every time there is a UIElement ? I am looking for something like Auto-resize animation

Comment: And what is your problem? You don't know how to resize controls in WPF?

Comment: @Maxim Edited the question

Comment: Another one question: how many elements can be placed in one cell during your animation? Two or any count?

Comment: Minimum 1 and maximum 3